# JPA & Criteria API specific selection, extract with select

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

the task is to group events by a specific day, to do this, I have to pull the day out of the date and group the records by it.
We used to use MySql and this code worked as it should:

```
public static Specification<AllFile> findByGroup(FileFilter fileFilter) {
    return (Specification<AllFile>) (root, query, cb) -> {
        final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (fileFilter.getStart() != null && fileFilter.getEnd() != null) {
            Date date = new Date(fileFilter.getStart().getTime());
            date.setHours(0);
            date.setMinutes(0);
            date.setSeconds(0);
            date.setDate(1);

            predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), date));
            predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), fileFilter.getEnd()));
        }
        else if(fileFilter.getStart() != null) {
            Date date = new Date(fileFilter.getStart().getTime());
            date.setHours(0);
            date.setMinutes(0);
            date.setSeconds(0);
            date.setDate(1);

            Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(date, 1);

            predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), date));
            predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), newDate));
        }

        if (fileFilter.getRoute() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("route"), fileFilter.getRoute()));
        }

        if (fileFilter.getDevice() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("device"), fileFilter.getDevice()));
        }

        if (fileFilter.getType() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), fileFilter.getType()));
        }

        if (fileFilter.getUser() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("user"), fileFilter.getUser()));
        }

        if (fileFilter.getDeleted() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("deleted"), fileFilter.getDeleted()));
        }



        query.groupBy(cb.function("day", Date.class, root.get("created")));
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
}
```

But after switching to Postgres, this approach does not work.
I need to send something like

```
select extract(day from allfile0_.created) as dd
from all_file allfile0_ 
where allfile0_.created>='Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' and allfile0_.created<='Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' 
group by dd
```

instead of this

```
select allfile0_.id as id1_0_, allfile0_.added as added2_0_, allfile0_.comment as comment3_0_, 
allfile0_.created as created4_0_, allfile0_.deleted as deleted5_0_, allfile0_.device_id as 
device_13_0_, allfile0_.duration as duration6_0_, allfile0_.mark as mark7_0_, allfile0_.path as 
path8_0_, allfile0_.recognition as recognit9_0_, allfile0_.route_id as route_i14_0_, allfile0_.size 
as size10_0_, allfile0_.type as type11_0_, allfile0_.updated as updated12_0_, allfile0_.user_id as 
user_id15_0_ 

from all_file allfile0_ 

where allfile0_.created>='2019-10-01 00:00:00' and allfile0_.created<='2019-10-04 00:00:00' 

group by extract(day from allfile0_.created)
```

is it possible to get what i nedd with Criteria API? Asking for advice about custom selection, to select only what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
query.groupBy(cb.function("day", Date.class, root.get("created")));
```

to

```
query = cb.createTupleQuery();
    root = query.from(AllFile.class);
    query.select(root.get("created")).
            groupBy(cb.function("day", Integer.class, root.get("created")));
```

After which the code worked as it should